# If column has certain value, the next column displays value for a number of cells

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck in this issue. Considering that in column “value” the number 1 appears, then the next column "trigger” displays the number 1 in the next 5 cells.

Please consider the following example:

```
Index     values
1          0
2          0
3          1
4          0
5          0
6          0
7          0 
8          0
9          0
10         0
11         1
12         0
13         0
14         0
15         0
16         0
17         0
18         0
19         0
20         0
```

The expected result should be as follows:

```
Index     values     trigger
1          0           0
2          0           0
3          1           0
4          0           1
5          0           1
6          0           1
7          0           1
8          0           1
9          0           0
10         0           0
11         1           0
12         0           1
13         0           1
14         0           1
15         0           1
16         0           1
17         0           0
18         0           0
19         0           0
20         0           0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
m = df['values'].eq(1)
df['trigger'] = df['values'].where(m).ffill(limit=5).mask(m).fillna(0, 
                                                                    downcast='int')
```

Or

```
df['trigger'] = (df['values'].shift().where(lambda x: x.eq(1))
                             .ffill(limit=4).fillna(0, downcast='int'))
```

**Output**

```
print(df)

    Index  values  trigger
0       1       0        0
1       2       0        0
2       3       1        0
3       4       0        1
4       5       0        1
5       6       0        1
6       7       0        1
7       8       0        1
8       9       0        0
9      10       0        0
10     11       1        0
11     12       0        1
12     13       0        1
13     14       0        1
14     15       0        1
15     16       0        1
16     17       0        0
17     18       0        0
18     19       0        0
19     20       0        0
```

You could use `.fillna(df['value'])` if you want keep values of column `values`